# Access functions across Angular controllers without $scope or $watch

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service which should share a location to many controllers

```
angular.module("StockSampleApp")
.service("Location", function () {
    this.currentLocation;
})
```

I have a main controller which changes the services currentLocation.

```
angular.module("StockSampleApp")
    .controller("MainController",["Location",function (Location) {

        this.locations = [
            { Id: 1, Name: "UK Warehouse Group" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "Britania Warehouse" },
            { Id: 3, Name: "Warehouse Limited" }
        ];

        //Sets initial value for the service currentLocation variable
        Location.currentLocation = this.locations[0];

        //When location is changed it update the service currentLocation variable
        this.changeLocation = function (location) {
            Location.currentLocation = location;
        };

        this.getLocation = function () {
            return Location.currentLocation;
        };

    }]);
```

I have a grid controller which uses the services. When the main controller updates the service currentLocation I want to run the `GetData()`

```
angular.module("StockSampleApp")
    .controller("GridController", ["Location", function (Location) {

        this.products = [];

        this.page = {
            totalProduct: 242,
            currentPage: 1,
            itemPerPage: 10
        };

        this.GetProducts = function(){
            this.products = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < this.page.itemPerPage;i++){
                //Makes Random Id
                var randomSkuId = (this.page.currentPage * 10) + i;

                this.products.push({
                    sku: randomSkuId,
                    title: "Product Title - " + randomSkuId,
                    onOrder: randomSkuId + 2,
                    due: randomSkuId - 2,
                    stockLevel: randomSkuId + 10,
                });
            };
        };

        this.GetProducts();

        this.pageChanged = function () {
            this.GetProducts();
        };

        this.getLocation = function () {
            //When location change update data in table - call GetProducts() and set currentPage = 1
            return Location.currentLocation;
        };

}]);
```

Comment: `"I dont want to use $scope and $watch."` - why?

Comment: Because I dont use the $scope parameter in my controllers. Dont want them to be inconsistent so some use $scope and some dont.

Comment: If you want to have the same instance of your service you should use `factory` instead of `service`. Read: https://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

Comment: You're not being 'inconsistent' by injecting $scope in your controllers - you can still use `$scope.$watch` even if you don't want to use `$scope.locations` instead of `this.locations`, for example.

Comment: @TomePejoski I will check this out thank you.

Comment: Your right $scope is okay to be used if I use it sensibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a controller, AngularJS automatically provides you with an instance of **$scope** to use, I don't understand the reasoning behind not wanting to use an already provided ressource, especially when the **$watch** function inside **$scope** is exactly what you need to achieve your goal.

```
$scope.$watch(
  function () { return Location.currentLocation.id; },
  function (oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
);
```

If you still don't want to use that, you can use this dirty workaround to periodically check if your service updated.

```
var currentLoc = Location.currentLocation;
setInterval(function () {
  if (Location.currentLocation.id !== currentLoc.id) {
    // do stuff then
    currentLoc = Location.currentLocation;
  }
}, 100); // adjust the interval to your taste
```

But I highly recommend against this since the solution above is simple and straightforward

Comment: People don't want to use $scope directly sometimes, as it's easily abused.

Comment: Thanks your right $scope is okay to use and make you write less code since you dont have to reference controller alias or the controller.

Comment: @dijam Aliases have their uses too - $scope could cause bugs where you'd use ng-if or ng-switch or similar directives which delete scopes from the DOM. It's upto the programmer to decide which one is best in a given situation, but I don't agree with your reasoning here.